# Error Select App Engine SDK directory creating Google App Engine project

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, pycharm

[image: app engine project settings]

Here's the exact error I got when I try to create a new project in PyCharm. It won't let me create a project for some reason and I was wondering if anyone else ran into this problem and/or knows how to solve it. I have both Python 2.7 and GAE SDK installed.

> Select App Engine SDK directory

Comment: Try pointing your SDK to google-cloud-sdk\platforms\google_appengine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Try pointing your SDK to google-cloud-sdk\platforms\google_appengine"
this worked!